# https website does not open with Chrome and Requests but works with firefox when using Proxy

Tags: python, google-chrome, ssl, firefox, python-requests

I am trying to access a webpage, url - https://www.ticketmaster.com/member/payment_options. I can open it using Google Chrome, Firefox and Python Requests as well.
Now, I want to access the same page using a dedicated proxy from stormproxies. I follow the proxy setup on Firefox and Chrome, as well as use those in Requests code. The webpage opens up well in Firefox, but not in Chrome. It just keeps on waiting for the sever to respond. Same thing happens with Requests code. It times out if I use a timeout parameter.

Here is the Requests code I am using:

```
import requests

proxy = '<proxy>'
proxies = {'http': 'http://{}'.format(proxy), 'https': 'http://{}'.format(proxy)}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'www.ticketmaster.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)
# s.proxies.update(proxies)
url = 'https://www.ticketmaster.com/member/payment_options'
r = s.get(url, timeout=30)
print(r.content.decode())
```

This code would work fine, but as soon as you uncomment the line `s.proxies.update(proxies)`, it would throw TimeoutException.

The bigger issue here is that even Google Chrome isnt working.
The only reasons I could figure out is that Firefox has its own Proxy setup, but Google Chrome rather uses Windows Internet Explorer proxy settings and security settings.

Let me know if any of you have come across this or if know a solution.

Comment: `<H1>Access Denied</H1>` ,`Are you sure the session is appropriate?`

Comment: Yes, it is. May be your IP is blocked.